# How to get decimal value from UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have my database in Sqlite and the field name is Amount with float datatype.now the value of amount is entered in textfiled.so my question is how to get decimal value from textbox?

Comment: m not getting ur question clearly..do you want that if input is 15.75 u should get 0.75 ?Please elaborate ur question with an example..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
float amount = [yourTextField.text floatValue];
```

**EDITED**

yes as taskinoor mentioned you should first check weather your text field contains any alphabets or not.

to check, try this

```
    NSString *aString = @"22.60Hello";
    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];

    if ([aString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        NSLog(@"This string contains illegal characters");
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 5):

```
float f = [myTextField.text floatValue];
```

Note that you should check yourself that the text field contains a valid number. From [NSString manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html),

> The floating-point value of the receiver’s text as a float, skipping whitespace at the beginning of the string. Returns HUGE_VAL or –HUGE_VAL on overflow, 0.0 on underflow. Also returns 0.0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number.

This method won't tell you that the input `abc` is not a valid number.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *decimalvalue=[NSString stringWithString:[txtfield.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Get the value from textbox and store in string. And you need to just convert this string to float value and insert in database.

this might work :

```
NSString *myString = (string initialization here);
float stringFloat = [myString floatValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
float decimalNum = [textfield.text floatvalue]
```

Comment: sorry.. got confused as i'm into other languages as well.. hehe